# NextJS server side renders even without getXProps?

Tags: next.js

This code is in a page file in NextJS. Although I'm not using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` it still performs server side rendering.

Is this by design? The docs would imply that these get functions are required: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io",
});

const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  {
    rates(currency: "USD") {
      currency
      rate
    }
  }
`;

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EXCHANGE_RATES);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Loading</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.rates.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.currency}>
            {item.currency} - {item.rate}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Home />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

Comment: are you seeing this when running `next dev` or `next build && next start`?

Comment: How do you know it is performing server-side rendering?It does not look like it is doing any server-side. You should see the loading paragraph until your apollo query is complete. Sometimes it is very fast and will cache it.

Comment: @SamuelG next dev

Comment: @SirCodesAlot when I disable JavaScript I can see the content is still being rendered to the HTML.

Comment: @Evanss run it using `next build && next start` there are some caveats when running in dev mode and calls like `getStaticProps` will be called on every request. I know you not using it, but worth a quick test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Production mode**

The page provided has no `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`. It's statically optimized (pre-rendered at build time).

So, when you request this page in a browser, you will see a pre-rendered HTML content in the response. Disabling JavaScript does not affect it.

If you navigate to the page by using client-side `next/link` or router the page will be rendered at client-side without making a request to a server.

**Development mode**

In Development mode this page would be both - server-side rendered and client-side rendered.

If you'd request the page by typing address in a browser it will be pre-rendered at server-side.

If you navigate to the page by using client-side `next/link` or router the page will be rendered at client-side without making a request to a server (you will see only Webpack Hot Module Replacement request).